# Uncheck checkbox on click button

Tags: jquery

I am appending button on checkbox click, but need to uncheck when I close the appended button.

```
$(".left-menu input[name='freeAsset']").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.search_lable').append('<li><button type="button" class="btn-close image" aria-label="Close" style="display: inline-block;">' + $(this).parent('div').children('span').text() + '<span aria-hidden="true" id="' + this.id + '">×</span></button></li>');
    $('.filter-label li .btn-close span').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });
  } else {
    $(".search_lable").find("button:contains(" + $(this).parent('div').children('span').text() + ")").filter(function() {
      return $(this).parent('li').length > 0;
    }).remove();
  }
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/rb82t0g5/5/)**

Comment: do you want to uncheck the checkbox after closing the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From question i understand that OP need to uncheck the check box after closing the button. So i did the following way.

```
$('.filter-label li .btn-close span').click(function(){
      $('input[type=checkbox][id='+$(this).attr('id') +']').prop('checked',false);// Newly added code to uncheck the checkbox.
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jqme9cwd/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/6vu97mex/)**.

Since you're appendin an `li` element when the user check, you need to remove the parent `li` not the button itself when the user uncheck, the just add `.closest('li')` before removing :

```
$(".search_lable").find("button:contains(" + $(this).parent('div').children('span').text() + ")").filter(function() {
  return $(this).parent('li').length > 0;
}).closest('li').remove();
___^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Adam could you please tell us why you've accepted the newest answer to your question what is almost a copy of the old answers here?

Answer (score 0):

In `else` you trying to select button and remove it using `.remove()`. So you should select `li` parent of button using `.parent()` and remove it.

```js
$(".left-menu input[name='freeAsset']").click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.search_lable').append('<li><button type="button" class="btn-close image" aria-label="Close" style="display: inline-block;">'+ $(this).parent('div').children('span').text() +'<span aria-hidden="true" id="'+this.id+'">×</span></button></li>');
    $('.filter-label li .btn-close span').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    });
  } else {
    $(".search_lable").find("button:contains(" + $(this).parent('div').children('span').text() +")").filter(function () {
      return $(this).parent('li').length > 0;
    }).parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li>
    <div class="label-cont clearfix">
      <input type="checkbox" name="freeAsset" value="valuable" id="Skills1">
      <label for="Skills1" class="chk"></label>
      <span class="txt">Soft Skills</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label-cont clearfix">
      <input type="checkbox" name="freeAsset" value="valuable" id="Skills2">
      <label for="Skills2" class="chk"></label>
      <span class="txt">Technical Skills</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="filter-label clearfix search_lable"></ul>
```

Also you can use simpler code as shown in bottom

```js
$(".left-menu input[name='freeAsset']").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).parent('div').children('span').text();
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('.search_lable').append('<li><button type="button" class="btn-close image" aria-label="Close" style="display: inline-block;">'+ text +'<span aria-hidden="true" id="'+this.id+'">×</span></button></li>');
  else 
    $(".search_lable li button:contains("+text+")").parent().remove();
});    
$(document).on('click', '.filter-label li .btn-close span', function(){
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li>
    <div class="label-cont clearfix">
      <input type="checkbox" name="freeAsset" value="valuable" id="Skills1">
      <label for="Skills1" class="chk"></label>
      <span class="txt">Soft Skills</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="label-cont clearfix">
      <input type="checkbox" name="freeAsset" value="valuable" id="Skills2">
      <label for="Skills2" class="chk"></label>
      <span class="txt">Technical Skills</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="filter-label clearfix search_lable"></ul>
```